# Add text after certain line

Tags: awk, sed

I have big file which has following lines

```
abc_a
some lines
abc_b
some lines
abc_c
some lines
abc_d
some lines
abc_e
some lines
abc_f
```

I want to add number incremental starting from 1 after every **abc** lines something like

```
abc_a1
some lines
abc_b2
some lines
abc_c3
some lines
abc_d4
some lines
abc_e5
some lines
abc_f6
```

Is it possible with sed or awk?

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`:

```
awk '/^abc/ { $0 = $0 (++a) } 1' file
```

With `perl`:

```
perl -lpe '/^abc/o and s/$/++$a/e' file
```

or

```
perl -lpe '/^abc/o and $_ .= ++$a' file
```

With `vim`:

```
:let a=1
::g/^abc/ s/$/\=a/ | let a+=1
```